# Проводник кэширует эскизы, даже после отключения кэширования

Tags: windows, безопасность, кэширование, windows-7

Решил отключить кэширование эскизов в проводнике windows.

Сделал это по [гайду](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-thumbsdb/5f86cfd9-3696-4629-ba1f-029996969ea7) и получил неожиданный результат. Файлы кэша (например `thumbcache_256.db`) все ещё блокируются проводником и удалить их можно только после его завершения. Проверил содержимое и оказалось что там до сих пор сохраняются миниатюры некоторых файлов.

Я не смог определить почему одни файлы сохраняются в кэше, а другие нет. Могу сказать только что оригинальные файлы, чьи миниатюры сохраняются в кэше - это jpeg файлы с разрешением больше 1000*1000, но другие файлы подходящие под эти параметры не попадают в кэш. В кэше всегда сохраняются одни и те же файлы, я проверил это удалив кэш, после перезагрузки открыл папку с картинками и при проверке вновь созданных файлов кэша обнаружил там эскизы этих картинок.

В чём может быть причина и как я могу отключить кэширование эскизов окончательно?

Я пробовал гуглить, но ничего полезного не нашел, моя последняя надежда на сообщество SO.

#### UPD

Моя задача - отключить кэширование эскизов, не отключая при этом сами эскизы. Я хочу с удобством использовать проводник, но не хочу что бы на общем компьютере оставались следы просмотренных мной файлов.

Если это не выполнимо, то есть нельзя отключить кэш эскизов, не отключая функциональность эскизов - напишите об этом, с ссылкой на какое-то доказательство, например на оф. документацию, это будет считаться ответом.

Comment: Многие просмотрщики картинок тоже сохраняют эскизы. Может, это они шалят?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, эти файлы я не открывал. Только открыл папку в проводнике и сразу же создаются файлы с их эскизами

Comment: А может этот гайд поможет лучше https://computer76.ru/2018/04/09/windows-thumbnail-cache/?amp

Comment: Попробуйте используя утилиту [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) отключить все нестандартные (не от Microsoft) расширения проводника

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сделано. Ничего не изменилось. Включил обратно

Comment: "NoThumbnailCache" и "DisableThumbnailCache" были отключены для всех ветвей? Это "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" и "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" (HKLM+HKCU)

Comment: @Daemon-5 да. Это не имеет смысла с точки зрения логики (я же настраивал для одного пользователя - себя), но я сделал это в всех ветвях и не получил результата

Comment: А я бы таки проследил procmon-ом за действиями Проводника, а затем прошелся бы по ветвям реестра, которые он читал. Может чего и попалось бы подозрительного

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, эту проблему нельзя решить по хорошему.

Проводник просто игнорирует настройки реестра, поэтому я запретил запись в директорию `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, оставив только возможность чтения списка файлов и их удаления.

Спасибо [terry60](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10794-thumbnail-cache-enable-disable-2.html#post2662498)

Я пока что не буду отмечать это как ответ на вопрос и подожду некоторое время, вдруг нормальное решение все же существует. Если нет, то это ещё один аргумент против использования windows.